# Count and remove duplicates in a list of strings but add the duplicate count to the key (any idiomatic java8-esque way?)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an input string (delimited with `&`) containing the following terms :

```
GenericRequest.param[i]
SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ
GenericRequest.param[i]
```

I would like the output to get "consolidated" (and delimited with a `&`) with a minor twist:

```
GenericRequest.param[i]=2
SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ
```

So far, I can `.split("&")` and `.filter(s -> s.endsWith("[i]")` but that leads me to individual strings; i need visibility into all strings so i can effectively count dupes, remove dupes and then add this extra bit of metadata to the relevant key (in this case, counting duplicates of `GenericRequest.param[i]`, removing duplicates, and augmenting it with `=2`.

I can accomplish this by building a frequency count of filtered keys (ending with `"[i]"`) and adding that to a list of unfiltered keys, but I just don't know how to do it in an idiomatic java8 way.

**Edit**: Here is what a complete string looks like

`GenericRequest.param[i]&SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ&GenericRequest.param[i]`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
String str = "GenericRequest.param[i]&SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ&GenericRequest.param[i]";
String result = Arrays.asList(str
                      .split("&"))
                      .filter(s -> s.endsWith("[i]");
                      .magic(?);
```

Comment: Could you post complete code? with samples of input text in String and the method you tried

Comment: @Saravana I've edited my post with the actual string, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, first am grouping by key and counting its value, then mapping key and value to a String

```
    String str = "GenericRequest.param[i]&SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ&GenericRequest.param[i]";
    Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.stream(str.split("&")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(map);
    List<String> list = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + (e.getValue() == 1 ? "" : "=" + e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
```

output

```
{SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ=1, GenericRequest.param[i]=2}
[GenericRequest.param[i]=2, SpecificRequest.param[i]=XYZ]
```